# Beginner: Is there a way to calibrate 2d interpolation without doing it frame by frame?

Tags: grease-pencil, interpolation

I'm learning blender and trying out animating with grease pencil with the hopes of creating 2D animations for web (if anyone got any tutorials I'd gladly accept links). When I try to interpolate between two different shapes I get weird behaviour. [See this gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApVa8.jpg). How would I go about changing this animation to behave as expected, with a more natural transition?

Right now I got 3 key frames at 1, 30, and 60 with 1 and 60 being the square and 30 being the circle and then just interpolating between them.

I know of the "To Sphere"-function, the square-to-sphere was just an example, I'm looking for a more general solution if there is one.

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: The most important thing in this interpolation is the order and stroke way. For example, if you started drawing something from the right, the second drawing should be done so too. I don't think it works like that in blender. I have not found any tips or tutorials on this. In Open Toonz you have this same feature, plus you can enable guided vector drawing, which shows you exactly the order and way of strokes, and it works good like that. But I am not sure how it fix it in Blender too.